# Is it possible to use two different drivers for sql server on the same machine. Say 2000 and 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use two versions of sql server on the same machine. I have sql server 2000 driver installed on the system. Can I also install sql server 2008 driver on the same machine and use both side by side?

Comment: Yes, you can use both drivers side by side

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use the SQL 2000 and SQL 2008 driver on the same machine at the same time.